# @keyup.enter is not working with <cleave>

Tags: validation, vue.js, materialize

```
 <div class="input-field">
   <cleave :options="{
 blocks: [20],
numericOnly: true
          }"
id="userId-input" type="text" @keyup.enter="validateUserID">
</cleave>
      <label id="userId-label" for="userId-input"> User ID</label>
    </div>
```

The above code worked when cleave is removed and input tag is placed.How do I make it work for cleave ?

Comment: `keyup.native.enter`?

Comment: Wonderful
That did the trick.
Thanks a lot!